# Liferay + Ubuntu 14 + Glassfish - 1GB RAM

Tags: java, ubuntu, glassfish, liferay, server

I have a personal server with `Ubuntu 14` and 1GB RAM. I would like to configure `Liferay` running in a `Glassfish` in this server.

I'm trying, but the initialization process is giving to me this message:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000c8bd7000, 84496384, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 84496384 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/glassfish-3.1.2.2/domains/domain1/config/hs_err_pid6797.log
Command start-domain failed.
The DAS was stopped
```

Can someone suggest some configuration that I can use without change the server physical memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You may encounter out-of-memory errors when launching the GlassFish
>   with Liferay portal. To avoid these errors, set larger initial and
>   maximum memory heap sizes with the -Xms and -Xmx options on admin
>   console.

If you can't increase the RAM you may try the "Liferay with Glassfish Bundle". This is a preconfigured Glassfish server with Liferay Portal already installed. It is available at http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases.

According to the [wiki docs](http://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+with+GlassFish) it has the following requirements:

- Memory: 1GB RAM Disk Space: 500MB
- System Architecture: X86/SPARC
- Operating System: Solaris/Linux/MacOS X/Windows/AIX
- JDK 1.6.x/1.5.x (Only 1.5.x on Mac)

Comment: The wiki page was last updated 2008. Memory requirements have raised in the last 6 years. Virtual Memory might help, at the cost of low performance